# I want to change background color before selector when on mouse over html tag article

Tags: html, css

I want to change background-color when on mouse over "Article" tag to change background-color of class overlayLink

This's my code

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlayLink {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.overlayLink:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
article {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="overlayLink">a</a>
  <article>
    abcdefghijk
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Then apply it to the article tag not the div

Comment: can u provide us the screenshot what u exactly want?

Comment: He wants to change the background-color of .overlayLink when hovering .parent.  Try this :
 `.parent:hover .overlayLink { background-colore: #000}`

Comment: You can't change the property `.overlayLink ` only with CSS, as it is in before the `article` tag. so you should use javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlayLink {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.parent:hover .overlayLink {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
article {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="overlayLink">a</a>
  <article>
    abcdefghijk
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful.

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlayLink {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.parent:hover .overlayLink {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
article {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="overlayLink">a</a>
  <article>
    abcdefghijk
  </article>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlayLink {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.overlayLink:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
article {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="overlayLink">a</a>
  <article>
    abcdefghijk
  </article>
</div>
```